# Does anyone know how to render different images on different parts of a 3D t-shirt?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

[A prototype but can only render an image to a fixed size and position on the 3D shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H99oA.jpg)

Does anyone know how to render different images on different parts of a 3D t-shirt?
For example, I would like to place a design on the back of the shirt and the logo on the front, or place the logo on the sleeve and have different designs on the front of the shirt.

I am trying to create a 3D t-shirt model like the ones above but allows users to have images on different parts of the shirt instead of just like the image above where the image is fixed to a position on the clothe.